# How do I show progress spinner anywhere I want?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, progress

I want to be able to show the progress spinner anywhere I want: Inside UITextField, Inside UITextView, Inside UIImageView, etc, etc. How do I do that? I am supposing that simply calling

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

is not sufficient. I don't mind doing it in storyboard or programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [UIActivityIndicatorView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html). It's a UIView subclass, so you should be able to specify the position programatically or via interface builder.